# ace python mode how to implement custom object properties and methods autocomplete and association

Tags: javascript, python, editor, ace-editor

For example, if I import a test and the test has different properties and methods, I want to prompt for the properties and methods on the test when I execute the test.and continue to enter characters to prompt for the properties and methods on the test after the prompt pops up. Filter the display.

```py
import test
test.a
test.b
```

The function I want to achieve is as described above, my idea is to click . I want to get the current object that I want to get the properties and methods of, read a json file through this object to get its properties and methods, and then add a custom completer, and at the same time add a custom object in . I'm not quite sure how to do it.